# Create Posterous like functionality for my website?

Tags: php

Well, the problem is i am building a web app which allows users to post on their web page from their email itself . The technically the users are group of people ( its confined to a small team ) who would like to post from time to time about the activity they do ( its regarding the fest of my college). to make it simple for them , i thought it will be better if they just send a mail to post@mydomain.com and that will get posted to their respective web pages created by me . i am a novice php programmer and have no idea on how to proceed on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea.

Just give them all a Posterous account but then use the Posterous API to extract the data and put it all into your own website.

I used this idea with a single account on a website to permit a "late breaking news" feature, should work with multiple accounts too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would create a cron job that checks the inbox for post@domain.tld. If it finds a new email from a registered email, it will read the email for the content and then post it to the right site (the script will pull the info based on the email address). This is only but one of the ways to do what you want.